# Looking for a book where the planet is a device to rebuild the universe

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a scifi book with an old guy and a group of youngsters that find an anomaly on a planet that looks like a massive pit but ends up being a gate to another world created by this race of aliens that are top shaped with tentacles coming from their mouths.

The old man turns out to be one of them but had forgotten everything until it started to come back when he came to that world. also the world has a seemingly infinite number of land types that cycle randomly, and when a person goes through this gate they get send to a specific land type and their body is changed in order to fit that space.

I think the plot revealed that the planet was a control device used to rebuild the universe. if anyone could help me that would be awesome.

Comment: thank you so much. its been years since i read one of the books and was wracking my brain trying to remember it.

Comment: Why is this the duplicate question when it is much older than the other one?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be **Midnight at the Well of Souls** by **Jack L Chalker**, its the first in the **Well of Souls** series, 10 books about the Well World

Well of Souls

1. Midnight at the Well of Souls (1977)

Below average in height and unprepossessing in appearance, Nathan Brazil is an unassuming if cynical starship owner, carrying passengers and cargo for a living - hardly the sort of person to hold the fate of the entire universe in his hands. 
But when Nathan detours from his route to answer a distress call, a hidden stargate hurls him and his passengers to the Well World, the master control planet for the cosmos. Billions of years ago, a godlike race unlocked all the secrets of space and time and remade the universe according to their grand design. Then they vanished and left behind the Well World to maintain the pattern of the universe. 
Now someone is searching for the planet's hidden control room - the Well of Souls - to seize control of the cosmos. Nathan must stop them, but this planet causes bizarre metamorphoses in visitors, changing them into centaurs, mermaids, and giant insects seemingly at random. As a result, Nathan no longer recognizes his friends, let alone his unknown enemies. His task seems hopeless - until his long-suppressed memories begin to return and he realizes who he really is.

2. Exiles at the Well of Souls (1978)
3. Quest for the Well of Souls (1978)
4. The Return of Nathan Brazil (1979)
5. Twilight at the Well of Souls: The Legacy of Nathan Brazil (1980)
6. The Sea Is Full of Stars (1999)
7. Ghost of the Well of Souls (2000)

Watchers at the Well

1. Echoes of the Well of Souls (1993)
2. Shadow of the Well of Souls (1994)
3. Gods of the Well of Souls (1994)